# How to add a new item on a child grid on kendo-ui grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How can I achieve this scenario using kendo-ui: 
I have a grid that has the names of students and a child-grid with all the scores in each class. My data source is hierarchical and comes from a RavenDB database [Id, name, [scores]]. How can I add a new score through a button in the same row of the student name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need `toolbar: ["create"]` in your detail grid

See [**Kendo UI grid Edition demo here**](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-popup.html)

Comment: hi HaBo. Thanks for quick response. I know how to do this using this approach. However i need a button on the same row of the student name, because some times the arrow sign on left side will be invisible.

Comment: Use field template to create button and take help of $.ajax to load a add form, after form submit refresh the grid.